# How to place image at the center of the document in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms

How to place image at the center of the document (both horizontally and vertically) in case of `WebBrowser` control in Windows Forms?

The following code works in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/3es05myx/) but it doesn't work in the `WebBrowser` control:

```
this.webBrowser.DocumentText =
                "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                "img.center {" +
                    "position: absolute;" +
                    "top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;" +
                    "margin: auto;" +
                "}" +
                "</style>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<img class=\"center\" src=\"https://d1u2uhea8ugy8e.cloudfront.net/info/static/img/globals/loading.gif\">" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

And here is the expected behavior:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a div and give the center class to that div not to the img tag.

Check it out this example.

```css
.center{
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center;   
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:300px;
  padding-top:130px;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
   <img src="https://d1u2uhea8ugy8e.cloudfront.net/info/static/img/globals/loading.gif">
<div>
```

Comment: Hahaha very nice question. you should check your JSFiddle in internet explorer. You are using `webBrowser` control and its capability is same as IE.

Comment: Can you also help me with text alignment (both horizontally and vertically too)?

Answer (score 1):

```
img.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; //half of image height
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px; //half of image width
}
```

Try to use this code.